# Dojo - Giving multiple className in domConstruct.create()

Tags: css, dojo, styles, multiple-inheritance

I am new to DOJO toolkit and still learning. I have a situation in which i want to give multiple css classes to the element created by dojo's domConstruct.create() method.

I created table element and four columns - 'td' elements with `domConstruct.create()` method. each column is styled differently.

I created my class -'errors-alignment' and have existing class 'error'.

If i add inline styles for more styling, it works.

```
domConstruct.create('td' , { className:'error',style:{....}},...)

className:'error-alignment error' //two classnames do not work either
```

But i can not have  inline styles and can not modify existing class.

Is there anything existing in dojo or css to help me providing multiple css to an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var newNode = domConstruct.create('td' , { 'class':'error' }, parentNode);
```

You can also use `dojo/dom-class` and `dojo/dom-style` to modify the class and style of an already existing node.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom-class.html

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom-style.html